# Krusader: drag'n'drop file to terminal adds newline before closing quote

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, drag-and-drop, krusader

When I drag and drop a file from Krusader to my terminal, it quotes the filename with single quotes but adds a newline before the closing quote.

I then have to do Ctrl-C to correct the quoting before I can go on with my command.

In case it's not clear, here is how it looks in Terminal:

```
 $ cmp '/docs/photos/20180102_161315.jpg
 > '
```

I searched the configuration but couldn't find where this is defined.

How can I re-define Krusader's quoting when dragging a file to the Terminal?

(Ubuntu 20.04, Krusader 2.7.2, KDE Frameworks 5.68.0, Qt 5.12.8)

**Update:**
This actually seems to be related to the interaction between Krusader and `gnome-terminal` (v. 3.36.2).

- drag'n'drop from Krusader to gnome-terminal: adds newline
- drag'n'drop from Krusader to Konsole: works OK.
- drag'n'drop from Files to gnome-terminal: works OK.